# Python regexp to match numbers with spaces

Tags: python, regex

I'm regexp newbie and I need some help.
I have text which represents table. I know that it will consist of 7 columns:

```
| int | int mixed with -. | unicode string with everything | float | float | int | float |
```

problem is that float is expressed using spaces between thousands (1234,43 => 1 234,43).
Moreover string can contain spaces and end with numbers.
I tried something like this (for each line striped of new line char):

```
regex = re.compile(r"(\d+) ([\d.-]+) (.*) ([\d+ ]?\d+,\d+) ([\d+ ]?\d+,\d+) (\d+) ([\d+ ]?\d+,\d+)$", re.UNICODE)
w = regex.findall(line)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work in all cases. Some test data:

```
49 602 DSKOD SMCX 262,59 1 131,30 1 1 131,30
49 602 DSKOD SMCX 3 5 262,59 1 131,30 1 1 131,30
50 61-201 łóćźż 1 2 669,50 334,75 1 334,75
51 1-214 AÓŻĆÓDS" 70,35 350,18 3 105,53
```

Cases with thousands are problematic as I'm getting:

```
[]
[]
[(u'50', u'61-201', u'\u0142\xf3\u0107\u017a\u017c 1 2', u'669,50', u'334,75', u'1', u'334,75')]
[(u'51', u'1-214', u'A\xd3\u017b\u0106\xd3DS"', u'70,35', u'350,18', u'3', u'105,53')]
```

In 3rd example I would like `2` at the end of string to be in next column.
Do you know have some clues how to match this properly, on Python 2.7? I'll fight with this unicode later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `[\d+ ]?`.  This matches zero or one of digit, plus, space.  The OTHER problem is using spaces for column separators and within fields without some kind of quoting, but this works for your data.  I also changed the 2nd column which had an extra `.` and the 3rd column to grab only non-space characters:

```
#!python3
# coding: utf-8
import re

data = '''\
49 602 DSKOD SMCX 262,59 1 131,30 1 1 131,30
49 602 DSKOD SMCX 3 5 262,59 1 131,30 1 1 131,30
50 61-201 łóćźż 1 2 669,50 334,75 1 334,75
50 61-201 łóćźż 1 669,50 334,75 1 334,75
51 1-214 AÓŻĆÓDS" 70,35 350,18 3 105,53
'''.splitlines()

regex = re.compile(r"(\d+) ([\d-]+) (.*?) ((?:\d{1,3})?(?:\ \d{3})*,\d{2}) ((?:\d{1,3})?(?:\ \d{3})*,\d{2}) (\d+) ((?:\d{1,3})?(?:\ \d{3})*,\d{2})", re.UNICODE)
for line in data:
    print(regex.match(line).groups())
```

Output:

```
('49', '602', 'DSKOD SMCX', '262,59', '1 131,30', '1', '1 131,30')
('49', '602', 'DSKOD SMCX 3', '5 262,59', '1 131,30', '1', '1 131,30')
('50', '61-201', 'łóćźż 1', '2 669,50', '334,75', '1', '334,75')
('50', '61-201', 'łóćźż', '1 669,50', '334,75', '1', '334,75')
('51', '1-214', 'AÓŻĆÓDS"', '70,35', '350,18', '3', '105,53')
```

Comment: I had to provide more details to description. I ended up editing your suggestion and I came to something like this: `r"(\d+) ([\d.-]+) (.*) ([(\d+ \d+)|(\d+)]+,\d+) ([(\d+ \d+)|(\d+)]+,\d+) (\d+) ([(\d+ \d+)|(\d+)]+,\d+)$"`. I still have problem with taking thousandth digit from string into the float. Do you happen to know some trick to force this?

Comment: Your new cases have spaces in the 3rd field.  Since spaces are used to separate columns this is confusing without some form of quoting.  If there are no digits in the 3rd column you can use my updated answer for your new data, but the 3rd line has a digit so it breaks.  There is no way to tell if the digits belongs with the string or with the float.

Comment: I got it to work for your data, but note that the new line of data I added is still ambiguous.  In the 4th line, there is no way to tell if the string ends in a 1, or the number is "1 669,50".  Do you have the freedom to generate the data using a better format?

Comment: Unfortunately no :/ this is output from PDF file and tool `pdftotext` .. I won't comment how good idea was to send data to analysis in such form. Luckily bad cases doesn't happen that often and I could go through them by hand ... Thx for you help!

Answer (score 1):

I'll break this in lines:

```
r = re.compile(r"(\d+) 
                 ([\d.-]+) 
                 ([^ ]*) 
                 ((\d+ ?)+,\d+) 
                 ((\d+ ?)+,\d+) 
                 (\d+) 
                 ((\d+ ?)+,\d+)$", re.UNICODE)
```

Changes are on the unicode part, to not be so greedy and avoid spaces, and then in the float parts. It will have the problem of floats not having a comma.

On your first line:

```
In [21]: r.findall(l)
Out[21]: 
[('49',
  '602',
  'DSKODSMCX',
  '2 262,59',
  '262',
  '1 131,30',
  '131', #!
  '1',
  '1 131,30',
  '131')] #!
```

The lines marked with #! are extra captures, resulting from the nested group I used to repeat the "\d\d\d " pattern.

On another sample:

```
In [23]: l2 = '49 602-1 DKSAJ 231 442 123,2 1 123 123,4 1 1 533 123,2'

In [24]: r.findall(l2)
Out[24]: 
[('49',
  '602-1',
  'DKSAJ',
  '231 442 123,2',
  '123',
  '1 123 123,4',
  '123',
  '1',
  '1 533 123,2',
  '123')]
```

Comment: Thx, I have used something similar to this. Up voted because your answer was also useful!